# http.client.RemoteDisconnected for random files from list of urls

Tags: python

I wrote a script to automaticly download files from a list of urls using urllib.request.

```
for url in addresses:
    file_name = url.rsplit('/', 1)[-1]
    file = os.path.join(directory, file_name)
    urllib.request.urlretrieve(url, file)
    print(" %-15s %-10s %25s" % ('--', file_name, 'downloaded'))
```

and sometimes I get `raise RemoteDisconnected("Remote end closed connection without"
http.client.RemoteDisconnected: Remote end closed connection without response` and the script stops. There are like 100 urls in the list and I can get that error when downloading 3rd, 25th or 89th file, whatever. I mean I can get that error for n'th file, but when I run my sript again, the n'th file could be downloaded correctly. It's random.

How to fix that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to keep the execution going on after a fail, use `try`, `except` -

```
for url in addresses:
    file_name = url.rsplit('/', 1)[-1]
    file = os.path.join(directory, file_name)
    try:
        urllib.request.urlretrieve(url, file)
        print(" %-15s %-10s %25s" % ('--', file_name, 'downloaded'))
        print(count, '/', len(addresses))
    except RemoteDisconnected:
        print("url {} did not return a valid response".format(url))
```

Now to solve this problem further, you could keep on trying till a url responds without timing out like so -

```
valid_response = False
while not valid_response:
    try:
        urllib.request.urlretrieve(url, file)
        valid_response = True
    except RemoteDisconnected:
        pass
```

This is kind of *brute forceish* but will keep trying till you get a valid response

Comment: thank you so much! now it works fine! off topic: why is downloading soooo slow? is it urllib or something else?

Comment: Probably your internet?

Comment: nope. The downloading speed is much faster when I download those files straight from browser

Comment: Okay, then you might need to add the time it takes to retry for a file, it'll add up to total download time